# Minted \setminted is undefined control sequence

Tags: minted

I am trying to use minted to highlight some code in a Latex document.

I am trying to use the \setminted command to set a global, document wide, style.

But when I attempt to compile the document, I receive the error:

```
> ! Undefined control sequence. <recently
> read> \setminted
```

Relevant latex code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted[python]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,bgcolor=LightGray,linenos}
```

Does anyone here know why the command \setminted is not a valid minted command despite being in the docs?
Thanks

EDIT: added { as to \setminted line, but results in the same error.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, comment out the `\setminted` and compile. Then look in the `.log` file, near the end you'll find a list of packages and their versions. Which version of `minted` do you have?

Comment: The `\setminted` command has been added in version 2.0 (released 2015/01/31). Update your TeX distribution.

Comment: I think that you are correct.
Updating fixes the problem.
Thank you to all who commented!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to outdated software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating fixes the problem. Thank you to all who commented

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `{` for the argument of the `\setminted` command. It should be `\setminted[python]{frame=lines,framesep=2mm,baselinestretch=1.2,bgcolor=LightGray,linenos}`.

Comment: Thanks Herb, well spotted.
I still get the same error though....

Comment: Can't help you there since I get no error once I fix that problem. What distribution are you using and is it up to date?

Comment: Updating fixes the problem. Thank you to all who commented